# How to check string for an array of words, matching it precisely

Tags: php, arrays, strpos

I'm trying to use strpos() to search a PHP string for specific words, as part of a function to sniff out a user's U.S. military service and display a message thanking them for their service. The problem is, for U.S. Air Force (USAF) veterans, the message appears *twice* because it also sniffs out the "USA" portion (which is a separate acronym for U.S. *Army* veterans.)

```
$p1Name = "Mr. John Smith";
$p2Name = "SSgt. John Doe, USAF";
$milbranches = array("USAF", "USMC", "USCG", "USN", "USA");
foreach ($milbranches as $mil)
    {
    if(strpos($p1Name, $mil) !== FALSE OR strpos($p2Name, $mil) !== FALSE)
        {
        echo "Thank you for your service.";
        }
    }
```

The OR statement to sniff this out from either `$p1Name` or `$p2Name` appears to work fine, but because `$p2Name` in this instance contains `USAF`, therefore satisfying a match for both `USAF` and `USA`, this yields the output of:

`Thank you for your service.Thank you for your service.`

There has to be something, maybe with preg_match() (I'm very unfamiliar with string comparison in PHP) or something that can tell it to only pay attention to the entirety of the phrase, and not pick out individual characters that are a match?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Break the foreach loop when it hits the first coincidence.

```
$p1Name = "Mr. John Smith";
$p2Name = "SSgt. John Doe, USAF";
$milbranches = array("USAF", "USMC", "USCG", "USN", "USA");
foreach ($milbranches as $mil)
    {
    if(strpos($p1Name, $mil) !== FALSE OR strpos($p2Name, $mil) !== FALSE)
        {
        echo "Thank you for your service.";
        break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I knew it would be something that simple! This worked, thanks. I tried setting a variable `$thanksShown = 1;` where your `break;` is initially, and then tried to put `&& !isset($thanksShown)` in the conditional statement, but that didn't work. This did though, so, thanks again!

Comment: You must then keep the array sorted. Meaning USA has to be after USAF in the array otherwise USAF would never be found, but in this sense, you mine as well not even include USA, unless they wanted to do something unique for each branch or something. So it's not perfect, but would work in this case.

Comment: The Error lies in the code finding both USA and USAF in the string p2Name.

Comment: Also you can get rid of USAF, because you have it covered with USA, and thus you gain performance saving loops, as @Mike explained.